# Which PayPal API will achieve crowd payments

Tags: paypal

My application already receive payments using Stripe API. Once payment is received, I must pay affiliates related to the transaction. This could be 1 to many recipients.

I want to use PayPal, I want to wire an API into my application so that I may pay all pending payments by clicking a "release funds" button...clicking the release funds button would pay related recipients to their email address from a paypal account that I will keep flush with funds.

**Which PayPal API will achieve this?** (paying many recipients from one paypal account)

I've done a lot of research on this and alternatives.  Before I spend valuable dev time on this, I need to know I'm heading down the right path so any advice would be most helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/) API will do it, but you'll need to get MassPay enabled on your PayPal account in order to use it.  It's free, but it's just not enabled by default.

You could also look into [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/), specifically the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API.  In that case you would build a script that loops through all your recipients and sends payments one at a time.

Comment: thanks for the response (again) - looping through recipients is fine, are there any advantages or disadvantages to either one?  If one can simply flip through and send payments, what is the benefit to using MassPay over Adaptive?

Comment: With MassPay you can send 250 payments in a single request, and the sender pays the fee, but it's a max of $1.00 no matter how much you're sending.  With the Pay API you're limited to 6 receivers, and the fees are more expensive, but you can adjust whether or not the sender or receiver(s) pays the fees.